# Force reload page in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

When using Thunderbird as feed reader, I often run into situation when a new item pops up in the feed but the new content is not displayed when I open it. It is caused by misconfigured caching. All items in the feed link to the same page, only to its different parts. When reading the first item, the page is cached; when a new item is added, the page is fetched from cache.

The best way to fix this would be to fix the linked page’s caching, but you cannot fix the whole world. It is responsibility of the client to handle even these broken pages.

In Firefox or any other browser, I would force reload the page using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, but in Thunderbird this does nothing. Another force-reload shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> is assigned to Reply to all in Thunderbird. I know that just switching tabs reloads the page, but that keeps loading the old cached version.

Is there a way to force refresh of the page? Is it possible to delete just the one page from the cache? What is in the cache that is deleted by pressing the Clear now button in Edit → Options → Advanced → Network & Disk Space?